# Is perfect isotonic probability calibration realistic?

Tags: classification, overfitting, calibration, isotonic, lightgbm

I work with a labelled tabular dataset of about 1 million observations, with the target being binary. The dataset is heavily imbalanced - about 0.5% positive class.

I have trained a gradient boosting tree-based classifier (LightGBM) to predict the binary class, obtaining a good baseline in terms of precision and recall to further improve upon.

After fitting and hyperparameter tuning on a training set (95% of samples), I perform probability calibration using isotonic regression on a held-out calibration set (2.5% of samples). Worth noting that I use stratified sampling to ensure consistent class distribution across set splits.

Although calibration improves classification metrics, the calibration curves raise some concern in me as the calibrated model curve appears to match perfectly the 45-deg benchmark. In comparison, the uncalibrated curve is extremely jagged.

[image]

I understand isotonic regression is prone to over-fitting, so my question is:

*How plausible is it for a calibrated curve to be perfect or is this a classic example of overfitting?*

If it's the latter, how can I apply regularization to remedy it? Note I am using the scikit-learn CalibratedClassifierCV implementation in Python.

---

I feel I need to provide updated information on my question, after more careful inspection of my code (thanks @Eike P. for the leads).

In my first post, I attached a plot of the reliability curves using the calibration set on which the calibration model was fit - hence I presume the overfitting.

I now attach the corresponding plot using a different held-out set.

[image]

It is clear the fitted calibration model has a weakness at a probability of around 35%, but otherwise it fairs well I think compared to the uncalibrated predictions.

Still, I would welcome advice/views as to whether it is useful to reduce overfitting for the calibration model and how to achieve it.

Comment: 1) Is this on a separate test set, i.e., *not* the validation set you're calibrating on? 2) How exactly are the points in those graphs computed / how many predictions is each of them averaged over? Can you maybe also show a histogram of the predicted probabilities, as is usual best practice?

Comment: @EikeP. (1) Calibration was performed on a completely separate set from training. Fine-tuning was performed using cross validation. (2) I have updated the embedded figure to include predicted probability histograms. I am now using 10 bins for both the reliability curves and the histograms (in the first version of this thread, I shared reliability curves computed with 20 bins). Note y axis is log-scale

Comment: It does seem very unlikely that it would really lie *exactly* on the diagonal, especially since in the mid-range you really don't have that much data... that's why I was asking whether you're plotting the reliability diagram from the data on which you calibrated, or from on a completely unseen extra test set. On the calibration set this would be expected; on a completely unseen test set not so much.

Comment: How are your bins determined? Doesn't seem to be fixed-width, is it quantile binning or something like that? And how are the points in your plot related to the bins? Are they the center points?

Comment: Note that if IR were overfitting (to the calibration set), you would see poor performance on your test set.

Comment: @EikeP. I now get what you mean...Indeed the reliability diagrams were plotted from the fitted data. I attached an updated plot using an unseen set. The bins are constructed as equal width. Not quite sure how bin points are computed...I am using sklearn.calibration.CalibrationDisplay.from_estimator() with default arguments https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibrationDisplay.html#:~:text=A%20calibration%20curve%2C%20also%20known,will%20be%20passed%20to%20matplotlib.

Comment: The two images look identical to me. Are you sure the second image is what you intended?

Comment: @8e9yQBKVlIDwoIVegfkJ my apologies, though I am quite certain I uploaded the right figure - don't know what happened. I hope now the figure to be fixed.

Comment: You need to evaluate the calibration out of sample. Perfect calibration like that happen when you evaluate the spline on the same sample it was calibrated (the exact same or something leaky). You need to build a robust split (splitting on time and or / ids). Then split with enough data. I would proceed in the following fashion: 60%, 20%, 20%. The first slpit to calibrate the model, second one to calibrate the spline, last one to evaluate both out of sample.